# Undefined Index in codegnniter website

Tags: codeigniter

Someone help me for resolve this issue. Site url is mewatnews.in.

Error is

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: subclass_prefix

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 369

Backtrace:

File: /home/mewat567news/public_html/index.php
Line: 298
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information. CodeIgniter's index.php references require_once at the very end:
    require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
Is this what your index.php says?
Check the capitalization when you extend CI_Controller or CI_Model